# dygraph: x-axis y axis set min and max values

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am displaying a few graphs  in different frames and I would like to have the same min and max values for the axis in all of them.

If I understand well, I can use the valuerange property for the Y axis.

What is the equivalent for the X axis ? I have been looking in the documentation and  I cannot find it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`dateWindow`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow).

You may also be interested in the [synchronizer extra](http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html), which will keep your chart axes in sync for you.

Comment: Thanks - dateWindow does what I need . But I do not know what is synchroniser extra!.

Comment: found out synchroniser - very nice .